# Stop Ubuntu asking for password to mount second drive

Tags: mount, authentication, gvfs

Whenever I turn on my machine and browse to the second hard disk in nautilus it asks me to authenticate to mount the drive.

I can find guides on how to turn on this behavior, but not to de-activate it, and can't seem to follow the steps backwards.

The disk is automounted and below is a screenshot, please let me know what other information you need

[image: disk manager details]

Comment: How is the drive formatted? NTFS/EXT4 ?

Comment: It's formatted as EXT4

Comment: When is the password asked?

Comment: @Braiam, it's asked when I browse to it for the first time in the file browser. Isn't the file browser (windows explorer) called Nautilius in Ubuntu/Lubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "user" to your mount options to allow any user to mount the partition.  Your mount options in your image are just above the "Mount Point" label, on an unlabeled line starting "nosuid,...  You also seem to have something inconsistent on the location of the mount.  Did you want it under /mnt or under /media?  The /etc/fstab file is the location for what typically gets automounted, but you seem to have a GUI to edit it.  A second mount mechanism is through your desktop and typically mounts things under /media//.  Your image also seems to indicate a /dev/sdb1 mount using this mechanism, but I'm not sure that's the same as the uuid identified device.

Comment: Sorry, where are my "Mount options" and do you literally mean "user" or my username? Also I don't really mind where it mounts, where it is now, which is /media/martin/Data works fine for me, but if you've a solution that would leave it elsewhere, that's fine too.